# Select2 not working inside a bootstrap tab

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, jquery-select2

I have a few tabs for different languages in my form. 
I am trying to add a tags field with the select2 plugin.
In the tabs that is shown first it works fine, but when I switch to the other tabs it doest not display correctly.

Here's some code

```
<div class="nav-tabs-custom">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        @foreach($languages as $language)
            <li {{ $loop->first ? 'class=active' : '' }}>
                <a href="#insurance_{{ $language->code }}" data-toggle="tab">{{ title_case($language->native) }}</a>
            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        @foreach($languages as $language)
            <div class="tab-pane {{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}" id="insurance_{{ $language->code }}">
                <h4>Main</h4>
                <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('language.'.$language->code.'.tags') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                    <label for="{{ $language->code }}-tags">{{ __('tags',[],$language->code) }}</label>
                    <select name="language[{{ $language->code }}][tags][]" id="{{ $language->code }}-tags" class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple">
                        @foreach($tags as $tag)
                            <option value="{{ $tag->id }}">{{ $tag->translate($language->code)->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                    @if($errors->has('language.'.$language->code.'.tags'))
                        <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('language.'.$language->code.'.tags') }}</span>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>

   @push('scripts')
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Select2
        $("select.select2").select2({
            tags: true
        })
    })
</script>
@endpush
```

Here are some pictures
http://prntscr.com/n0w534
http://prntscr.com/n0w5b8

Comment: It's because the Select2 constructor relies on being able to read the dimensions of the input element, which cannot be done when it's not part of the DOM yet, or hidden. To fix this, instantiate the Select2 when the tab becomes visible. Depending on what tab controls you're using there should be some 'shown' events, or similar, which you can hook to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of @Rory McCrossan I researched and figured it out.

Here's the fix

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    changeSelect()
})

// Select2
function changeSelect() {
    $("select.select2").select2({
        tags: true
    })
}
```

It activates the function whenever a tab is changed